# Performance issues with large website

Tags: php, wp-admin, mysql, performance

I've been struggling with this website for a while now so any kind of help is deeply appreciated.

**Server configurations**

The website is running on a dedicated server from hostgator with the following specs:

- Intel Xeon-D CPU (8 Core / 16 Thread)
- 16 GB RAM
- CENTOS 6.9
- PHP 7.2
- PHP-FPM

**PHP.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 30
memory_limit = 1024M
```

**PHP-FPM settings**

```
pm = static
pm.max_children = 30
pm.max_requests = 500
```

**MySQL conf.**

```
query_cache_type=0
query_cache_size=0
thread_cache_size=10
table_open_cache=64M
tmp_table_size=512M
max_heap_table_size=512M
wait_timeout=3
interactive_timeout=10
key_buffer_size=256M
max_connections=150
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_buffer_pool_size=11G
innodb_log_file_size=1408M
innodb_log_buffer_size=128M
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=11
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
innodb_read_io_threads=16
innodb_write_io_threads=8
```

**DB total size:** 3.9G

**wp_posts:** 438,724 rows

**wp_postmeta:** 3,091,747 rows partitioned by post_id as the following:

- p0    post_id < 608883    691655 rows (posts from 2014 and older)
- p1    post_id < 671052    621995 rows (posts from 2015)
- p2    post_id < 736922    869995 rows (posts from 2016)
- p3    post_id < MAXVALUE  999652 rows

The website is using W3 Total Cache plugin along with CloudFlare

**The problems:**

- When publishing posts to the website it sometimes take up to 3 mins just to publish one post.
- Publishing posts also causes very high load on the server causing it to completely shutdown and I get error 524 message from cloudflare.
- Admin panel pages suddenly becomes very slow and then very fast again with no reason.
- Finally, widgets admin page is extremely slow and almost never completes loading due to very large page size (firefox network inspector showed that downloaded page size was about 30MB!!)

I can provide whatever additional info that may help.

Thanks...

**UPDATE:**

Slow query log is showing the following 2 queries a lot:

```
# Query_time: 3.495343  Lock_time: 0.000042  Rows_sent: 0  Rows_examined: 1
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1508709787;
UPDATE `wp_options` SET `option_value` = '1', `autoload` = 'no' WHERE `option_name` = 'nxs_v4APIMn';

# Query_time: 2.290696  Lock_time: 0.000108  Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 282657
# Rows_affected: 0
SET timestamp=1508710080;
SELECT post_date_gmt FROM wp_posts WHERE post_status = 'publish' AND post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment', 'pdfs', 'articles') ORDER BY post_date_gmt DESC LIMIT 1;
```

The first one is related to [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/social-networks-auto-poster-facebook-twitter-g/)

Comment: what webserver are you running on?

Comment: server could have disk problems ... see if you have a raid that is defect and maybe runs only on one disk ...

Comment: Is there any paging going on, at the server?

Comment: It is running on Apache

Comment: How can I check if it is RAID problem

Comment: Just takes one bottleneck to defeat everything else you've done, one or more can be produced by a range of different factors - including faulty or out-of-date software and seemingly minor misconfigurations. Regardless of the explanation, 3 minutes seems unacceptable to publish a post, but I'm not confident that an examination of hardware and db specs is going to lead to a solution. (Are error logs clear?) Maybe something will jump out for someone though...

Comment: Do you have access to your mysql slow query logs?  That is the first thing I would check.  You could run a plugin like [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) which will show you the database queries.

Comment: @CKMacLeod Yes, error logs are clear

Comment: @user42826 Yes, I have access to the slow log and it show some slow queries from time to time but I couldn't get any helpful information from it if you can guide me on how to analyze its output that would be great.

I've also used the query monitor plugin, it give different output every page load for the same page.

Comment: Can we safely assume you've tried the most basic troubleshooting stuff: Turned off all plugins? Switched to basic theme (Twenty Seventeen or such)? Optimized/Repaired DB?

Comment: @CKMacLeod I've disabled most of the plugins (It is a production site and some plugins are essential to its work). Right now I'm creating a replica of the website so I can completely disable all the plugins. But, as for DB repairs and optimizations, yes I've done that several times.

Comment: I guess creating a replica (staging) site might be another way to go if you really can't afford any downtime. In fact you might find out something if you created a fresh installation with everything the same except for a near-empty database with default php and sql configuration. Then tried it with a copy of the db, but with default settings, etc.

Comment: @CKMacLeod That is an interesting idea also. I will consider trying this.

Comment: In the mean time I'm getting a lot of slow queries mostly selecting from wp_posts table is taking a long time.

Comment: Determining if some poorly coded plug-in or theme function is making the queries extra slow would be the point of disabling the plug-ins and switching to a basic theme. With as big a db as you seem to have, it certainly stands to reason that the effects of bad coding or bad configuration would be amplified (and be harder to detect in the small db installation).

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
E) complete MySQLTuner report 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
df -h  for a linux/unix free space list by device, 
for server tuning analysis.

Comment: Please post TEXT results of A) SHOW INDEX FROM wp_options; and B) SHOW INDEX FROM wp_posts;   for analysis of the first two slow QUERIES in your question.

Comment: @AmeerElsherif Does your table `wp_options` have an index for column `option_name` ? Index will be needed for first query to perform well.  
For your second query, for the table wp_posts you need a combination index of  post_status  AND post_type.  You also need an index on post_date_gmt to cover the ORDER BY clause for performance.

Comment: Possibly relevant:  https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248207/simple-sql-query-on-wp-postmeta-very-slow