# how to Optimize Wordpress database for 10 million post?

Tags: database

i am trying to create a website with 10 million post but after half a million website posting goes too slow how i can optimize my database and import data like a new website

Comment: Possible dup of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/248207/simple-sql-query-on-wp-postmeta-very-slow

Answer (score -1):

You can build a database with connect your own AWS cloud hosting and can help via java script

```
<script>
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello JavaScript!";
</script>

<noscript>Sorry, your browser does not support JavaScript!</noscript>
```